# Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String

Tags: c#, string, datatable, guid

I am at the end of my knowledge and googled for the answer too but no luck :/

Week ago everything worked well.

I did a revert on the repository, recreated the tableadapter etc... nothing helped.

When I try to save in my application I get an SystemInvalidCastException at this point:

PersonListDataSet.cs:

```
partial class P_GroupTableAdapter
{
    public int Update(PersonListDataSet.P_GroupDataTable dataTable, string userId)
    {
        this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = userId;
        this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = userId;
        this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = userId;

        return this.Update(dataTable); **<-- Exception occurs here**
    }
}
```

Everything is stuck here because a Guid - and I checked the datatable preview with the magnifier tool its really a true Guid in the column of the datatable - can not be converted to a string ??? How can that happen?

Comment: Please show us your SQL.

Comment: Please show us the exception and stack trace, and show us the value of userID that you are passing in to the method.

Comment: Is @userId supposed to be a Guid? Then `["@userId"].Value` should be assigned with Guid value rather than with String.

Answer (score 6):

It's the other way around. Your userId is a string and you need a GUID value for your parameters:

```
 Parameters["@userId"].Value = new Guid(userId);
```

Provided UserId is in one of the supported formats for a GUID. The constructor [supports many formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx).

Edit, based on comments below:

It turns out that you are asking how to run a select statement like:

```
SELECT ....
WHERE '{BB6DFF45-FDA7-4155-86D0-0CBF129A9104}' = `domainname\\jondoe`
```

I think you should re-check your datamodel and find a solution.

Comment: userId is varchar here no Guid.

Comment: @user320460: That is exactly why you need to convert it to a Guid. The parameters are Guids, right?

Comment: userId = SamAccountName = "domainname\\jondoe"

Comment: @Henk

the error occurs when I try to save/update not when I do the select

Comment: DATASET ARE EVIL because this was the problem => In the tableadapter property window you go to Update/InserCommand parameter collection where you find all columns. One of the columns was defined as AnsiChar in a former revision it was a guid so I changed it back and Save now works!!!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
this.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = new Guid(userId);
this.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = new Guid(userId);
this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@userId"].Value = new Guid(userId);
```

Hope it helps!!!